# What is the set $\{h_{w,b}(x)=[[\langle w,x\rangle >b ]]\mid w\in \mathbb{R}^d\}$

Tags: machine-learning

In particular to the topic, what does $h_{w,b}(x)=[[\langle w,x\rangle > b]]$ means?

Comment: *Could* mean many different things.  Does this come from a source?

Comment: Homework in a course in machine learning. It says "Each classifier is a half space, but the margin doesn’t necessarily go through the origin." (the set in the topic is $\mathcal{H}_d$)

Comment: Could it be they mean it's just $h_{w,b}(x)=\langle w,x\rangle +b$?

Comment: Or it might be all the points $x$ such that $\langle w,x\rangle >b$?

Comment: Ok found the answer in the lecture notes, it's used in the course for indicators, it's 1 when the value in the [[]] is true and 0 otherwise

Answer (score 0):

In the course the lecturer uses it for indicators, which means $[[\langle w,x\rangle >b]]=\begin{cases}1& \langle w,x\rangle >b\\0& otherwise\end{cases}$

Comment: See [Iverson Bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) for a similar notation.